# Best way to flush or clear Ajax "temp" stuffs in IE7

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Can any one please let me know, that, i need to clear the "temp" files every time i run the ajax process using php.

Comment: You can't flush the temporary files from server/scripting side. What exactly is your situation?

Comment: if i did any changes in my .php file, which does no affect in IE7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi you please try this code on your header.tpl file. or use this as server side script. see here.

```
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Tue,01 Dec 1990 06:30:00 GMT">
```

or

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="Tue,01 Dec 1990 06:30:00 GMT">';
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid caching, you can append a unique number to the URL, e.g.

```
var url = 'something.php?' + +new Date;
url; // => "something.php?1273750710315"
```